# mysql query to select data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

### wall_paths (table)

[image: wall_paths]

### wall_dimensions

[image]

### dimensions (reference table)

[image]

> What I've got so far:

### Query

```
SELECT wall_paths.wall_id, wall_paths.wall_path, 
       dimensions.width, dimensions.height
FROM wall_paths
LEFT JOIN wall_dimensions
ON wall_paths.wall_id = wall_dimensions.wall_id
LEFT JOIN dimensions
ON wall_dimensions.dimension_id = dimensions.dimension_id
WHERE wall_paths.wall_id = 4;
```

### Result

[image]

The query is selecting redundant rows, I just would like to select the two paths along with the corresponding dimensions based on the wall_dimensions table. Something like below:

**Expected result**

[image]

**Result with `GROUP BY` in query**

[image]

Please help on how to select something like the above.

Note: I've tried `DISTINCT` as well on the query but returns an error.

Comment: did u try group by wall_path

Comment: Hmmm...is there a difference if you INNER JOIN the tables?  I wonder if the LEFT JOINs are somehow creating a CROSS JOIN-like product...

Comment: @VBlades, same result with INNER JOIN as well. I guess there is no major difference between the two.

Comment: It isn't clear how you link `path_id = 7` with `dimension_id = 4` and `path_id = 8` with `dimension_id = 5`?? Given `wall_paths` is linked to `wall_dimension` by `wall_id`, each of those 2 rows in `wall_paths` are linked to both rows in `wall_dimension`. So those 4 rows is exactly what we expect your query to do.

Comment: I don't understand why you consider one to be redundant. You have two dimension ids, so two results !?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query results are as expected, actually.  Makes sense when you see it, data-wise.  The data model is setup incorrectly for this query.

Fiddle (original data model): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c1bf/1

Fiddle (modified data model): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d9b0/5

Not saying you should change your model, just pointing out the query runs as expected with the current schema.

Comment: just a question, wouldn't be better if I insert the `dimension_id` in the `wall_paths` table than inserting the `path_id` to the `dimensions` table?

Comment: @vephelp: Yes, that would absolutely make more sense.  The dimension is an attribute of the wall_paths object, not vice versa.  Your goal with the dimensions table is to normalize the dimensions data; if you put path_id in there, it would defeat the purpose.  And then drop the wall_dimensions table as it's just redundant at that point (looks like it always was, tbh - there isn't any unique data in there).  Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/854344/1

Comment: @vephelp: Just to put it out there, I think this is where the original idea of the data model was headed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e162c/6.

Comment: alright! I've done that buddy! Added `dimension_id` to `wall_paths` table. Thanks a lot!